# Dynamic menu with materializecss

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, materialize

I have a question about a menu and submenu I want to make dynamic.
I have the following html

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menus" class="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'dropdown-button' : ''}}" 
           data-activates="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'Administracion' : ''}}">
    <span ng-bind-html="item.Nombre"></span>
    <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="Administracion" class="dropdown-content">
      <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Submenu" ng-init="$last && rebindDropDowns()">
        <a ng-href="{{subItem.Nombre}}" ng-bind-html="subItem.Opcion">{{subItem.Opcion}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="Solicitud" class="dropdown-content">
      <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Submenu" ng-init="$last && rebindDropDowns()">
        <a ng-href="{{subItem.Nombre}}" ng-bind-html="subItem.Opcion">{{subItem.Opcion}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have 2 submenus ("Administracion", "Solicitudes"), but only managed to show to "Administracion", in "Solicitudes" it shows me the same submenu of "administration".

That's because I have this line

```
data-activates="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'Administracion' : ''}}"
```

but if I do this it gives me error

```
data-activates="{{item.Submenu.length ? {{item.Opcion}} : ''}}"
```

Options can be "Administracion" o "Solicitudes"

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I worked, I did so now without the "{{}}" and operating normally.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menus" class="{{item.Submenu.length ? 'dropdown-button' : ''}}"
          data-activates="{{item.Submenu.length ? item.Opcion : ''}}">
        <span ng-bind-html="item.Nombre"></span>
        <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="Administracion" class="dropdown-content">
          <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Submenu" ng-init="$last && rebindDropDowns()"><a ng-href="{{subItem.Nombre}}" ng-bind-html="subItem.Opcion">{{subItem.Opcion}}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="item.Submenu.length>0" id="Solicitud" class="dropdown-content">
          <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Submenu" ng-init="$last && rebindDropDowns()"><a ng-href="{{subItem.Nombre}}" ng-bind-html="subItem.Opcion">{{subItem.Opcion}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

I leave if it helps someone. I hope so.